# Capture event involving the scanner

Tags: c#, winapi, wmi, wia, twain

I am trying to write an application that simply shows an alert when a user attempts to scan something. Is there an API that will allow me to do something like this in C#?

1. Run silently until a user initiates a scan from either the hardware (a scan button, aka a "push" scan) or from software on the computer (aka a "pull" scan).
2. Capture and pause the scan.
3. Show an alert with a continue button.
4. Resume or cancel the scan after user input on the alert.

This may also be used in conjunction with other 3rd scanner software. For example, both Adobe Acrobat and Microsoft Paint provide the user with an import from scanner button to "pull" an image from the scanner. I do not want to lose any functionality with my custom app.